DataDog can't receive my log when using Agentless mode
I'm experiencing issues with DataDog not receiving my logs in Agentless mode. Despite following the official tutorial, the logs are not being sent directly to the DataDog server as intended. Could someone assist me in resolving this issue?
My Spring boot's logback-spring.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="syslog" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>intake.logs.datadoghq.com:10516</destination>
        <keepAliveDuration>20 seconds</keepAliveDuration>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <prefix class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>abcabcabc %mdc{keyThatDoesNotExist}</pattern>
                </layout>
            </prefix>
        </encoder>
        <ssl />
    </appender>
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="syslog" />
    </root>

</configuration>

My spring boot pom version
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
</parent>

Other dependencies
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.6</version>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>

I have tried so many times with different ways, but not working.
